# Javascript Array Merging

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good evening guys, I have a Laravel project am working on and I need to merge some javascript arrays in a certain way:

```
// Note that this array can be on any length
const _arr1 = [213];
const _arr2 = [323];
const _arr3 = [342];
const _arr4 = [231];
```

and I have a second array like this:

```
//This array has the same length as the ones above
const _secArra = [232,423,422,423];
```

I want to merge them as so in this manner: I want to take `_secArra[]` and empty them in the array above and then get a result like this:

```
const _arr1 = [213, 232];
const _arr2 = [323, 423];
const _arr3 = [342, 422];
const _arr4 = [231, 423];
```

And each time `_secArra[]` has some values, it should empty in this array

```
const _arr1 = [213, 232,  //which is _secArra[0]];
const _arr2 = [323, 423,  //which is _secArra[1]];
const _arr3 = [342, 422,  //which is _secArra[2]];
const _arr4 = [231, 423,  //which is _secArra[3]];
```

Thanks guys

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas but he said _Thanks guys_

Comment: _"Someone has a genuine issue and instead of contributing, you are downvoting it!"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) - tl;dr: SO is not a free code-writing service

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
const _arr1 = _arr1.concat(_secArra[0]);
const _arr2 = _arr2.concat(_secArra[1]);
const _arr3 = _arr3.concat(_secArra[2]);
const _arr4 = _arr4.concat(_secArra[3]);
```

concat method is used to join two array

Comment: _"The `concat()` method is used **to merge two or more arrays**. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array."_ - `_secArray[0]` is not an array

Comment: @Andreas `concat` will also work with non-arrays as arguments `[1, 2, 3].concat(4)` produces `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the target arrays in an array and push the values to the arrays at the same index.

```js
const
    push = (arrays, values) => arrays.forEach((a, i) => a.push(values[i])),
    arr1 = [213],
    arr2 = [323],
    arr3 = [342],
    arr4 = [231],
    secArra = [232, 423, 422, 423];


push([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4], secArra);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
console.log(arr4);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: _"You could collect..."_ - Or how about OP first shows his approach or at least some effort on research before we add an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function based on an array of array in order to handle any number of array and any length of `_secArra`.

```js
const _arr1 = [213];
const _arr2 = [323];
const _arr3 = [342];
const _arr4 = [231];

const _secArra = [232, 423, 422, 423, 826, 999];

function emptyArrayInArrays(arrToEmpty, arrays) {
  arrToEmpty.forEach((x, xi) => arrays[xi % arrays.length].push(x));
}

emptyArrayInArrays(_secArra, [
  _arr1,
  _arr2,
  _arr3,
  _arr4,
]);

console.log('_arr1', _arr1);
console.log('_arr2', _arr2);
console.log('_arr3', _arr3);
console.log('_arr4', _arr4);
```

Answer (score 0):

by reverse your array and use of [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const _arr1 = [213];
const _arr2 = [323];
const _arr3 = [342];
const _arr4 = [231];

const targetArrays = [_arr1, _arr2, _arr3, _arr4];
const _secArra = [232,423,422,423];
for (let i = _secArra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    targetArrays[i].push(_secArra.splice(i)[0]);
}
console.log(_secArra);
console.log(_arr1);
console.log(_arr2);
console.log(_arr3);
console.log(_arr4);
```